# Javascript to get height of box dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, overflow

I have a table which displays some grid data for search results...Now the height of this table would vary each time.

So is there any way by which I could get the height of this dynamic table..

Basically I want to set an overflow:auto property for that table which would enable it to be scrolled on the iPad using 2-fingers (I cannot do the scrolling using 1-finger as that table rows does the drag action for 1-finger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#tableid').height();` will get you the height (with jquery). I'm not sure how that's relevant to your desire to use overflow:auto.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var elem = document.getElementById("elementId");
var elemStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null);
var height = elemStyle.getPropertyValue("height");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try jQuery's [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Dom element's hight using it's [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight) property.